# Problem with value of integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-verification

I calculate $\int \frac{dx}{\sin^2x+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan(\sqrt{2}\tan x)+c.$ And then I want to calculate $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sin^2x+1}$$. But $\tan\pi=\tan0=0$. So it seems that $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sin^2x+1}=0$, but it's not true. Where is mistake in my justification ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229955/problem-with-calculation-this-integral-int-0-pi-fracdx13-sin2x?rq=1

Comment: The function you found as the integral is discontinuous at $\pi/2$.

Comment: Also similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356523/what-are-the-restrictions-on-using-substitution-in-integration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+\sin(x)^2}=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin(x)^2}$$
And $\arctan \infty=\pi/2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sure ! I now see my mistake. Thank you very much for answer !

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

I made the same mistake before. Refer to [[Integral][Please identify problem] $\displaystyle\int \cfrac{1}{1+x^4}\>\mathrm{d} x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873537/integralplease-identify-problem-displaystyle-int-cfrac11x4-mathrm)

The reason of the problem is that $\arctan(\sqrt{2}\tan x)$ has a jump but the integral should be continuous, so in the two branches of the function (splitted by the jump point), you need to pick 2 different constants to make it continuous. It also apply to similar situations.